# How to prevent history state change with back button in modal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I click the Android back button my popup should close. It is not closing. Popup should not appear. I have to override the android back button action.

```
$ionicPopup.show({
    templateUrl: 'templates/time-picker-12-hour.html',
    title: '<strong>12-Hour Format</strong>',
    subTitle: '',
    scope: scope,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel'
    }, {
        text: 'Set',
        type: 'button-assertive',
        onTap: function (e) {

            scope.loadingContent = true;

            var totalSec = 0;

            if (scope.time.hours != 12) {
                totalSec = (scope.time.hours * 60 * 60) + (scope.time.minutes * 60);
            } else {
                totalSec = scope.time.minutes * 60;
            }

            if (scope.time.meridian === "AM") {
                totalSec += 0;
            } else if (scope.time.meridian === "PM") {
                totalSec += 43200;
            }
            scope.etime = totalSec;
        }
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this solution](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-the-hardware-back-buttons/1505/22?u=premiumfrye) (but don't forget to deregister your event handler--refer to [the docs for registerBackButtonAction](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

Edit: for answer permanence, code snippet to handle android back button :
`$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
//close your ionic modal here
}, 100);`